# How can i make this filter work the same in controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter data in my controller

**This works:**

```
<input style=" margin-left: 15px; margin-top :50px;   width:31%;"  class="form-control" ng-model="ValueSearch" type="text" placeholder="Sort..." id="searchCompanies" autofocus />

<li class="result" ng-repeat="c in CompanyDashData | filter:{companyName:ValueSearch} ">
```

**All I want to do is to achive the same but in controller, here is what ive tried:**

```
<li class="result" ng-repeat="c in CompanyDashData | filter:filterinControl ">
```

and then in my controller i made this function

```
 $scope.filterinControl  = function () {
        return $filter('filter')($scope.CompanyDashData,{companyName: $scope.ValueSearch});
 }
```

But it just returns all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've replaced

```
filter:{companyName:ValueSearch}
```

by

```
filter:filterinControl
```

So, if you want the behavior to be identical, `filterinControl` must be an object with a field named `companyName`, and a value being the entered value.

But that's not what it is. It is a function, which calls the filter again, and returns the filtered array. So you're applying, as a filter, a filtered collection.

What you probably want is

```
<li class="result" ng-repeat="c in filterinControl() ">
```

That will call the `filterinControl()` and iterate on the filtered array it returns.

Answer (score 0):

ummm.... u try do this:

HTML:

```
<li class="result" ng-repeat="c in filterinControl">
```

JS:

```
 $scope.filterinControl  = function () {
        return $filter('filter')($scope.CompanyDashData,{companyName: $scope.ValueSearch});
 }
```